# Passing function as a contructor argument not being properly recognized

Tags: c++

I've been trying to pass a function as a parameter of a contructor, but the compiler seems to recognize it as a contructor that simply accepts an integer, ratherthan a function that returns integer and shows an error that I am missing proper contructor (one that would accept a function).

Could anyone explain that behaviour? I am using Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int funct() {
    return 5;
}

struct button {
    button(int (*function)()) {
        //func = function;
    }
    int (*func)();
};


int main() {
    button(funct); //Error: no default contructor exists for class "button"
}
```

Comment: Looks like a use case for `std::function` in C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to define a default constructed `button` called `funct`. Your code is the equivalent of this:

```
button funct;
```

and this fails because `button` has no default constructor. What you need is something like

```
button b(funct);
```

Here, `b` is an instance of `button` constructed with the single parameter constructor.